# Delphi protected variables and constructor

Tags: delphi

I have written this simple code:

```
type
  TTestA = class
  strict protected
    a: integer;
  public
    f: integer;
    constructor Create(x: Integer);
  end;

type
  TTestB = class(TTestA)
  strict private
    c: integer;
  end;
```

I use `strict` because these classes are in the same unit as the `TForm1` class. Since `a` is protected by definition, it should be accessible only in subclasses, but then why this code doesn't work?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  K: TTestB;
begin
  k := TTestB.Create(3);
  value = k.a; //I cannot access a
end;
```

Also, the protected can be useful to create an abstract class. In C++, if I declare a constructor as protected, I cannot create an instance of the object and only subclasses can. Can Delphi do this?

I am having the same problem with the variable and the constructor.

Comment: You are asking two separate questions.  That is against StackOverflow guidelines.  Please move your abstract question to another post.

Comment: Regarding the first question: Do not make the mistake of confusing classes with units. TForm is not related to either of the classes TTestA or TTestB. But TTestB is a subclass (descendent) of TTestA, so they are related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in your own question:

> Since `a` is protected by definition **it should be accessible only in subclasses**

Regardless of the fact that `TForm1` uses a local `k` variable of type `TTestB`, since `TForm1` itself is not a subclass of `TTestA`, it does not have access to the `k.a` member.  `TTestB` is a subclass of `TTestA`, so internally it has access to `a`.

This is explained in more detail in Embarcadero's documentation:

[Classes and Objects (Delphi): Visibility of Class Members](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)#Visibility_of_Class_Members)

Answer (score 7):

**protected** access means "*accessible in the class and any sub-class*".

This means that `a` in your example will be accessible to methods in class **TTestB** but this does not extend to *consumers* of instances of **TTestB** (or **TTestA**).

The code in **TForm1** is part of a class which is *not* a subclass of **TTestA**.

Put another way, **TForm1** does not inherit from **TTestA** and therefore cannot access any *private* or *protected* members of `k`.